# Embedded system - external memory change

Tags: manual-testing, functional, embedded

I would like to ask this time your view on what aspects would you consider to tickle when a strategic component like memory is replaced (in embedded system).

Basically, the main goal is to ensure that the software/firmware can run smoothly without any problems, but due to drivers changes, memory partitions, memory access time or even memory technology replacement can lead to large change in the software/firmware infrastructure, so in cases like these what approach would you choose to validate the software/firmware?

Comment: too board, need to be more specific

Comment: I think that the answer should issue two types of embedded systems:
1. With embedded OS
2. without embedded OS

Comment: Voting to close; partly due to being too broad, and partly due to me not understanding why changing hardware wouldn't require a full regression test.